# Report Builder dependent parameter doesn't change when primary parameter does

Tags: parameters, reportbuilder3.0

I have two parameters in my Report Builder 3.0 report where one will give the current season (called Current_Season) and the second parameter will give the current season and the previous season (called Season_Selection).  The Current_Season defaults to the current season, but the user can change it once the report is run.

The issue I'm having is that the Season_Selection doesn't seem to be changing when Current_Season does once the report has been run and the user decides to look at a different season.

The way that I built the Season_Selection is that I input two default values that are dependent on the Current_Season and a Last_Season parameter.  So essentially the Season_Selection is dependent on two parameters.

Here is my expression for Current_Season: =Iif(Month(Today())>=9,Year(Today()) & "-" & Year(Today())+1,Year(Today())-1 & "-" &Year(Today()))

Here is my expression for Last_Season: =CInt(LEFT(Parameters!Current_Season.Value,4))-1 & "-" & CInt(Right(Parameters!Current_Season.Value,4))-1

And the Season_Selection default values are just @Current_Season and @Last_Season.

Do I have to build the parameters differently or is there a setting somewhere that I need to check?  I do have the "Always Refresh" bubble checked in the Advanced section of the properties for all parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the preceding parameters to create another dataset and then based the next parameter on that data set.